Encoding "MOV EAX, moffs32" on x86-64
I have stumbled across the "MOV EAX, moffs32" instruction while trying to understand x86-64.

As far as I can tell, this instruction would get encoded (with an moffs32 of 0x12345678) to just A1 78 56 34 12.
When I run this through a disassembler, however, I get garbage:
# objdump -D -b binary -mi386 -Mx86-64 -Mintel file.bin
00000000 <.data>:
   0:   a1                      .byte 0xa1
   1:   78 56                   js     0x59
   3:   34 12                   xor    al,0x12

Same goes for ndisasm:
# ndisasm -b 64 file.bin
00000000  A1                db 0xa1
00000001  7856              js 0x59
00000003  3412              xor al,0x12

I only get the instruction back if I disassemble it for x86, not x86-64 (ndisasm -b 32):
00000000  A178563412        mov eax,[0x12345678]
Why is that? The table states that the instruction is valid for 64bit after all.
I feel like I might be missing something fundamental here, but I can't figure out what.

Note that moffs32 does not mean a 32 bit offset. It means offset to a 32 bit operand (matching eax). Also read the referenced footnote #3: "operands specify a simple offset relative to the segment base, where 8, 16, 32, and 64 refer to the size of the data. The address-size attribute of the instruction determines the size of the offset, either 16, 32, or 64 bits."

@Jester I have read that sentence a couple times, but I didn't quite understand it. Makes a lot of sense now why it disassembled fine for x86, and why in user555045's answer an address size override pops up.
Thanks!

The 32 in moffs32 is only describing the operand-size, not the address-size.  The address-size is still 64-bit by default in 64-bit mode.
So it is valid in 64-bit mode, but you need more bytes for the offset, for example:
A1 78 56 34 12 00 00 00 00

That still encodes mov eax, [0x12345678], but now in 64-bit mode. This instruction is a rare case of encoding a 64-bit constant address. You can use it with a 32-bit address with an address size override:
67 A1 78 56 34 12

But note that this can be slower due to LCP stalls on Intel CPUs than the 7-byte encoding using the normal 8b 04 25 78 56 34 12 opcode for mov reg, r/m with the address as a sign-extended disp32.

Very interesting! Did I misread the table, or is there a mistake on the linked page? Do all instructions with a moffs other than moffs64 require the address size override?

I think Jester's comment anwered both of these questions. Thank you!

You can use it with a 32-bit address with an address size override: - but that can cause LCP stalls on Intel CPUs if the instruction isn't coming from the uop cache.  Does a Length-Changing Prefix (LCP) incur a stall on a simple x86_64 instruction? (@NyxCode).  So normally if you want to use a 32-bit absolute address that can fit in a sign-extended disp32, use that instead even though it costs an extra byte:  8b 04 25 78 56 34 12 using the normal mov reg, r/m opcode that isn't restricted to rAX
